# What is meant by "on se ramène par régularisation"?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, probability-distributions, translation-request, mathematical-french

I am currently attempting to translate the paper 'Sur l'équation de convolution $\mu = \mu \ast \sigma$' by Choquet and Deny.  In the paper, a locally compact abelian group $G$ and a positive measure $\sigma$ on $G$ are given and the measures $\mu$ which satisfy the convolution equation above are found. I've mostly been able to translate the paper, but there are a few phrases which I think are important which I don't understand.

The first phrase is

> Inversement pour montrer que toute solution $\mu$ bornée est périodique on se ramène par régularisation au cas où $\mu$ est une fonction $f$ bornée uniformément continue sur $G$, et l'on peut supposer G dénombrable à l'infini.

In particular, the following part

> $\mu$ bornée est périodique on se ramène par régularisation au cas où $\mu$ est une fonction $f$

What is meant there?

The second similar phrase I'm wondering about is

> ..., i.e. telles que les régularisées $\mu \ast \varphi$ soient des fonctions.

Finally, I'm also wondering about

> donc telle que $g_0(x) = 2 \alpha$ en tout point $x$ du symétrique de $S_\sigma$ [support of $\sigma$] par rapport à l'origine O, done du semi-groupe engendré.

I'd greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: I think they are saying that they prefer the regular ramen http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramen#Regional_variations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unsure what is meant by "régularisation". It might mean without loss of generality, in this case the first sentence translates to

> Conversely, to show that any bounded solution $\mu$ is periodic, it
>   suffices to show the case where $\mu$ is a uniformly continuous
>   bounded function on $G$, where $G$ is assumed to be a countably
>   infinite set.

As of the second sentence, you should provide the whole context. "Done" is not word in French, so your last sentence hardly makes sense. Perhaps you mean "donc", which translates to "thus"?

Comment: In supersymmetry, there is regularization by dimensional reduction

Comment: I'm no French speaker, but wouldn't it be "by regularization we reduce to the case where $\mu$ is a uniformly continuous bounded function..."?  "Regularization" here is presumably referring to the general technique of approximating a non-smooth "function" (here a measure) by smoother functions.

Comment: That would probably make more sense, but since we have very little context, it's hard to know what is meant.

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry, it was "donc".

Comment: Careful, "Dénombrable à l'infini" does not mean countably infinite. It is rather linked with a locally compact spaces. I think it means that the space can be written has a countabble compacts family

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien: Good guess.  The literal English translation would seem to be "countable at infinity" and that concept is discussed in [this MO post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/56275/is-a-connected-separable-locally-euclidean-hausdorff-topological-space-second-co).

Comment: Wasn't aware of the notion of "countable at infinity". Thanks for sharing. Even being French canadian studying in an English institution, I realize it's harder than I thought to translate mathematical concepts!

Comment: [Here](http://i.gyazo.com/2a7b0b8c943aa9d974fe59e5b96116b1.png) is broader context for the last sentence.